# iOS why backBarButtonItem is nil in this scenario

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I have a view controller that is embed in a navigation controller, and inside it there is a button that *shows* another view controller, like this:

[image]

In the second view controller, the value of `self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem` is nil, why please?

Though I can see the back button when I run the app, like this:

[image]

#### Update

I read that the back button in a view controller, is the responsibility of the navigation item of the previous view controller, and to be more presise, it is the responsibiliyt of the navigation item in the previous view controller.

so i tried to do this in the first view controller:

```
 self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem!.title = "Wdd"
```

but i got exception because backBarButtonItem is also nil in the first view controller.

#### update2

Guys look here please

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/NavigationControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011313-CH2-SW3

there is this sentence

> The navigation item associated with the current view controller provides the content for the center and right positions of the navigation bar. The navigation item for the previous view controller provides the content for the left position

Comment: in Which method you are checking the value of self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem?

Comment: Check in viewDidAppear

Comment: @PradipVanparia in the view did load method

Comment: @PradipVanparia kindly read my update, i read that the **previous** view controller is the one responsible of the back bar button. so there is no need to do anything in the second view controller, it should be enought to set the value of the back bar of the previous view controller and then the navigatio ncontroller will automatically put that value as the back button of the second view controller. right ?

Comment: @PradipVanparia or you mean that even in the first view controller, i should set the value of the back button in the view did appear method ?

Comment: first VC is your initial VC , in here back button not avaialble

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I know that, but the navigationItem in the first VC is the one responsible of controlling the back button in the second VC (at least that what I understood). Anyway, how can we solve that ? :)

Comment: @sarah, got your point.
First view controller is root controller of navigationcontroller.
root controller have not back bar button.
When another controller pushed in navigation then navigation controller will set back bar button for another controller.

Comment: Change the title of first view controller when second controller push in navigation

Comment: @sarah how can we get second controller's navigationItem in first controller. Because second controller is not pushed in navigation flow.
First VC is provides only content when SECOND controller is pushing into navigation.

Comment: @PradipVanparia the second is pushed, i showed you the screenshot of the second view controller. Plus, i don't want to change the title of the first VC when push the second VC, there is a button called back button and i want to learn how to use it :).

Comment: @PradipVanparia if you have a solution please write an answer for that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113146/discussion-between-pradip-vanparia-and-sarah).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution myself.

In the firstVC i do this in view did load:

```
backButton.title = "ddddd"
        self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backButton
```

and it works

i got the answer after this image :

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can add from Storyboard a navigation item in your second controller and set back button title. This way  `self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.title` will not be nil.

Comment: in this way, i will loose the default behaviour of the back button and i will need to write the code for that.

Comment: I tried it in my code and it works, it goes back to first controller.